# what's polymorphic type in C++?

Tags: c++

I found in one article saying "static_cast is used for non-polymorphic type casting and dynamic_cast is used for polymorphic type casting". I understand that int and double are not polymorphic types.

However, I also found that static_cast can be used between base class and derived class. What does polymorphic type here mean? Some people says polymorphic type means the base class with virtual function. Is that right? Is this the only situation? What else? Can anybody could elaborate this for me more?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all, the article is not completely correct.  *dynamic_cast* checks the type of an object and may fail, *static_cast* does not check and largely requires the programmer to know what they're doing (though it will issue compile errors for some egregious mistakes), but **they may *both* be used in polymorphic situations**.  (*dynamic_cast* has the additional requirement that at least one of the involved types has a virtual method.)

Polymorphism in C++, in a nutshell, is **using objects through a separately-defined interface**.  That interface is the base class, and it is almost always only useful to do this when it has virtual methods.

However, it's rare-but-possible to have polymorphism without any virtual methods; often this is a sign of either bad design or having to meet external requirements, and because of that, there's no way to give a good example that will fit here.  ("You'll know when to use it when you see it," is, unfortunately, the best advice I can give you here.)

Polymorphism example:

```
struct Animal {
  virtual ~Animal() {}
  virtual void speak() = 0;
};

struct Cat : Animal {
  virtual void speak() { std::cout << "meow\n"; }
};

struct Dog : Animal {
  virtual void speak() { std::cout << "wouf\n"; }
};

struct Programmer : Animal {
  virtual void speak() {
    std::clog << "I refuse to participate in this trite example.\n";
  }
};
```

Exercising the above classes slightly—also see my [generic factory example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832003/instantiating-classes-by-name-with-factory-pattern/1837665#1837665):

```
std::auto_ptr<Animal> new_animal(std::string const& name) {
  if (name == "cat") return std::auto_ptr<Animal>(new Cat());
  if (name == "dog") return std::auto_ptr<Animal>(new Dog());
  if (name == "human") return std::auto_ptr<Animal>(new Programmer());
  throw std::logic_error("unknown animal type");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) try {
  std::auto_ptr<Animal> p = new_animal(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "human");
  p->speak();
  return 0;
}
catch (std::exception& e) {
  std::clog << "error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  return 1;
}
```

It's also possible to [use polymorphism without inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041521/does-cs-file-have-an-object-oriented-interface), as it's really a design *technique* or *style*.  (I refuse to use the buzzword *pattern* here... :P)

Comment: Any type that can be used polymorphicly.

Comment: -1 All this may be correct & useful, but the question has not been answered in a clear way. Should never have been accepted.

Answer (score 20):

**static_cast** can perform conversions between pointers to related classes, not only from the derived class to its base, but also from a base class to its derived. This ensures that at least the classes are compatible if the proper object is converted, **but no safety check is performed during runtime** to check if the object being converted is in fact a full object of the destination type. Therefore, it is up to the programmer to ensure that the conversion is safe. On the other side, the overhead of the type-safety checks of dynamic_cast is avoided.

static_cast can also be used to perform any other non-pointer conversion that could also be performed implicitly, like for example standard conversion between fundamental types:

```
double d=3.14159265;
int i = static_cast<int>(d);
```

**dynamic_cast** can be used only with pointers and references to objects. Its purpose is to ensure that the result of the type conversion is a valid complete object of the requested class.

Therefore, dynamic_cast is *always successful* when we cast a class to one of its base classes.

```
// dynamic_cast
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

class CBase { virtual void dummy() {} };
class CDerived: public CBase { int a; };

int main () {
 try {
    CBase * pba = new CDerived;
    CBase * pbb = new CBase;
    CDerived * pd;

    pd = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(pba);
    if (pd==0) cout << "Null pointer on first type-cast" << endl;

    pd = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(pbb);
    if (pd==0) cout << "Null pointer on second type-cast" << endl;

    } catch (exception& e) {cout << "Exception: " << e.what();}
    return 0;
 }
```

**Compatibility note**:  dynamic_cast requires the Run-Time Type Information (RTTI) to keep track of dynamic types . Some compilers support this feature as an option which is disabled by default. This must be enabled for runtime type checking using dynamic_cast to work properly.

**Virtual Functions** are responsible for *Run-time Polymorphism* in C++. A class that has at least one virtual function has polymorphic type.

[Read More....](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)

Read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) too. It has been clearly written that`A class that declares or inherits a virtual function is called a polymorphic class.`

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. But I don't think you answered my question. My question is what's is polymorphic type. Not the difference between static_cast and dynamic_cast

Comment: Class that has at least one virtual function. You have already answered it in your question.

Comment: If you have no other method to make virtual: make the dtor be virtual, which it should always be in this kind of example anyway.

Comment: I did not copy it from your code. I copied it from the link that I have posted. I have already asked skydoor to read from the link that I have given for more details.

Comment: Ah, they're the ones to blame for using try-catch incorrectly here!

Answer (score 10):

Well, the answer is simple. A class having atleast one virtual function is called a polymorphic type. This can be only a destructor also.

So the following is a '*polymorphic type'.*

```
struct Test {
  virtual ~Test();
};
```

Comment: so the class without virtual function can always be casted using static_cast?

Comment: @skydoor:No, read my post. static_cast can perform conversions between pointers to _related classes_, not only from the derived class to its base, but also from a base class to its derived.

Comment: Its the other way around, a `dynamic_cast` can be performed only for a class with atleast one virtual function!

Answer (score 2):

I think the full phrase is "polymorphic type *casting*".  You are right that static_cast works on types that are not related by inheritance (double - int, etc) and the others answers point out how the casts work.

I don't think the statement implied the existence of a mythical polymorphic type though - just that static_cast also works on unrelated types.  The statement was a little confusing though and it's good to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I think that we always define/declare the destructor of any class as virtual especially in an inheritance tree. Then we can say that almost all classes in an inheritance tree are polymorphic.