# Creating new object with parameter

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, new-operator

```
void ChangeState(int newState)
{
    nextState = newState;

    //Change the state
    switch( nextState ) ///the change still will have a case for everything
    {
    case STATE_INTRO:
    {
        vec.pop_back();
        state ptr(new CIntroState);
        vec.push_back(ptr);
        break;
    }
    case STATE_MENU:
    {
        vec.pop_back();
        state ptr(new CMainMState);
        vec.push_back(ptr);
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

I have this function that allows me to change my current state; however, I thought about it and this is going to be a huge switch statement by the time I am finished. Currently, it already has about 10 states in it, this is just some sample code. I am trying to do something a little different, but I am not sure how to go about it.

```
void ChangeState(something)
{
    vec.pop_back();
    state ptr(new something);
    vec.push_back(ptr)
}
```

If I could bring it in this way, I could completely avoid the use of the switch statement and get the same end result. Does anyone know how to go about this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you want templates.

Comment: What makes each state different? Perhaps you just need a `State` class with data members that describe these differences rather than a separate class for each state.

Comment: What is know about something. If you give each state `something` its own type. could you know the type at compile-time. Or is it only possible to know it in run-time?

Comment: each states runs three functions, updatelogic, handling events, and drawing. I know each state and runtime/compile time. When to change states is all programmed in.

Comment: Incidentally, why the pushing and popping? Why not `vec.back() = new something;`?

Comment: Well, I was doing the pop back because the new something that is held in vec.back() is a smart pointer and I thought that I would have to popback in order to ensure the d-constructor was called; however, I never tested it with just switching what vec.back() was.. So I will try that out ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link compile-time polymorphism (i.e., templates) and run-time polymorphism, as ryanbwork suggests.  The challenge here is to try to avoid transforming your current form of repetitive code (the big `switch`) into a similarly verbose but more declarative form of repetitive code.

As [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032881/creating-a-new-object-from-dynamic-type-info) popular Stack Overflow question reveals, clone methods are usually the way one creates new instances of dynamically determined types at run-time.  Cloning is really a specialization of the more general factory pattern, and you could create a set of factories for your types whose definition would be only a little more verbose than your current enumeration presumably is:

```
template <class T>
class factory {
public:
   T* operator()() {return new T;}
};

factory<CIntroState> IntroState;
factory<CMainState>  MainState;
// etc...

template <class Fac>
void ChangeState(Fac newStateFactory)
{
   vec.pop_back();
   vec.push_back(newStateFactory());
}
```

Comment: aww, thank you. I think this pretty much covered my question! Thanks for the link btw!

Comment: Happy to oblige, @user1956980.  I notice from your other questions, though, that you don't seem to be in the habit of accepting answers.  Perhaps it's a feature of StackOverflow with which you are unfamiliar.  In any case, it's CUSTOM MADE for just this situation.  See instructions here:  http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: You are correct. That is a feature I was unfamiliar with! I have accepted your answer! thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a combination of [templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/) and [polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/). With templates, you don't need to enumerate all the different types that you may pass into a function, as this will be done for you during compilation. To store all of these different types in the same vector, you'll need to have them all sub class some super-type which then allows you to store them side by side in a vector of super-type.

Comment: I have them all taken from an abstract class so they all have the same type. I tried to accomplish this with templates, but with little success... ;)

Comment: Can you post the code you wrote that used a template function + the errors you were getting?

Comment: I think I got rid of it because of how frustrated I was at the time lol. I will have to rewrite it and try to mess with it again. For some reason, templates is something that I understand the concept behind them, but have not figured it out yet heh.