# Base class method not called on object of derived type: polymorphism without pointer and reference

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions

Consider a `Base` class and a derived class that inherits from it called `Child`.
Assume the `Base` class has a member function declared `virtual`, and that `Child` overrides that function.
I would like to declare a variable as a `Base` class object, initialize it using the `Child` derived class constructor, and then use the `Child` class version of the member function.
In other words, the following C++ program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual int give_number(int x) { return x; }
};

class Child : public Base {
public:
    int give_number(int x) { return x+1; }
};

int main() {
    Base base;
    Child child;
    Base child2;
    child2 = Child();
    std::cout << "Base says " << base.give_number(1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Child says " << child.give_number(1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Child2 says " << child2.give_number(1) << "\n";
}
```

results in the following output:

```
Base says 1
Child says 2
Child2 says 1
```

But I would instead prefer the following output:

```
Base says 1
Child says 2
Child2 says 2
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: `child2 = Child();` here's your bug. It's called object slicing. Use pointers for that (i.e. `std::unique_ptr<Base> b; b = std::make_unique<Derived>();`)

Comment: You need to use pointers or things like pointers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032361/whats-polymorphic-type-in-c

Comment: Virtual functions in C++ only work on pointers or references, your approach cannot work in C++. Change your Base and Child variables to be pointers and the code will work.

Comment: Important reading: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/4581301)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the statement:

```
child2 = Child();
```

You are [*slicing* the `Child` object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/4581301), which is why the `Child::give_number()` method is not being called.  `child2` is a `Base` instance, never a `Child` instance. During the assignment, only the `Base` portion of the new `Child` object is copied into `child2`.

You must use a pointer or reference when calling a virtual method polymorphically, eg:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual int give_number(int x) { return x; }
};

class Child : public Base {
public:
    int give_number(int x) override { return x+1; }
};

int main() {
    Base base;
    Child child;
    Child child2;
    Base& base2 = child2;
    std::cout << "Base says " << base.give_number(1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Child says " << child.give_number(1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Base2 says " << base2.give_number(1) << "\n";
}
```

Or:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual int give_number(int x) { return x; }
};

class Child : public Base {
public:
    int give_number(int x) override { return x+1; }
};

int main() {
    Base base;
    Child child;
    Child child2;
    Base* base2 = &child2;
    std::cout << "Base says " << base.give_number(1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Child says " << child.give_number(1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Base2 says " << base2->give_number(1) << "\n";
}
```

Or:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual int give_number(int x) { return x; }
};

class Child : public Base {
public:
    int give_number(int x) override { return x+1; }
};

int main() {
    Base base;
    Child child;
    //Base* child2 = new Child;
    std::unique_ptr<Base> child2 = std::make_unique<Child>();
    std::cout << "Base says " << base.give_number(1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Child says " << child.give_number(1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Child2 says " << child2->give_number(1) << "\n";
    //delete child2;
}
```